# Return not returning variable value

Tags: c++, return

I wrote a practice program for my class, and everything in it works except for returning the value of a variable. My question is, why isn't it returning the value? Here is sample code I wrote out to avoid having to copy and paste large parts of code that aren't relevant.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::cin;
using std::endl; using std::fixed;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw; using std::setprecision;

int testing();

int main()
{
    testing();

    return 0;

}

int testing() {
    int debtArray[] = {4,5,6,7,9,};
    int total = 0;

    for(int debt = 0; debt < 5; debt++) {
    total += debtArray[debt];
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: That code simply discards the return value. Try changing `testing();` to `std::cout << testing();` and see if you don't get something.

Comment: The `testing` function does indeed return a value. But you simply discard that value in the call. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: *"Here is sample code I wrote out to avoid having to copy and paste large parts of code that aren't relevant."* -- And we thank you kindly for that.

Comment: Thanks for the input and giving me your time. Unfortunately it seems all my mistakes turn out to be rookie mistakes that beg the reply "you should have known better".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, the function *is* returning a value. However, `main()` is choosing to ignore that return value.

Try the following in your `main()`:

```
int total = testing();
std::cout << "The total is " << total << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

The function does return a value.
You are not displaying the returned value on the screen so that is why you think it doesnt return a value

Answer (score 4):

`testing()` *does* return a value, but the value does not get used or saved anywhere. You are `using` std::cout, std::cin, std::endl, etc. but you aren't *using* them. I'm assuming what you wanted to do was display `total`. A program for that would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int testing();

int main() {
    int totaldebt = testing();
    cout << totaldebt << endl;

    return 0;
}

int testing() {
    int debtArray[] = {4,5,6,7,9};
    int total = 0;

    for(int debt = 0; debt < 5; debt++) {
        total += debtArray[debt];
    }

    return total;
}
```

What is happening in your code is (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize in any way) inside `main()`, `testing()` is called, goes through its instructions, and then the program moves on. The same thing happens if you call `printf` from `<cstdlib>`. `printf` is supposed to return the number of characters it displays, but if you don't store the result anywhere it just displays the text and the program continues.

What I have to ask is why are you `using` more than you actually make use of? Or is this not the complete code?

Comment: @ExpletiveDeleted Ah, alright, I was going to say that you were `using` so many things that you never actually made use of.

Answer (score 3):

`Return` is not equivalent to `print`. If you want the value the function has returned to display to stdout, you have to have a method of doing that. This is accomplished by printing the value that was returned using `std::cout` and the `<<` operator either in main or in the function itself

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfect but it does not takes the value which is being returned by function `testing()`
Try this, 
This will hold the data that is being returned by your `testing()` function

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::cin;
using std::endl; using std::fixed;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw; using std::setprecision;

int testing();

int main()
{
    int res = testing();
    cout<<"calling of testing() returned : \t"<<res<<"\n";
    return 0;

}

int testing() {
    int debtArray[] = {4,5,6,7,9,};
    int total = 0;

    for(int debt = 0; debt < 5; debt++) {
    total += debtArray[debt];
    }

    return total;
}
```